# Error when specifying Select2 data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm specifying the data for a `Select2` dropdown by using an external array but it keeps giving the following error. I'm using the latest `Select2 v4.0.3` so I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help is appreciated. The relevant code is given below. Note that I tried using a `<input>` element and the code worked as expected.

```
select2.min.js:21 Uncaught Error: Option 'data' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
    at String.<anonymous> (select2.min.js:21)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.2.js:384)
    at d.prepareOpts (select2.min.js:21)
    at d.prepareOpts (select2.min.js:22)
    at d.init (select2.min.js:21)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (select2.min.js:22)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.2.js:384)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.2.js:136)
    at jQuery.fn.init.a.fn.select2 (select2.min.js:22)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (bio?id=3&action=display:773)
```

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdown" multiple="multiple" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2"></select>
```

**JQuery**

```
var arr = [{id:0, text: "red"}, {id:1, text: "blue"}]; 

$("#dropdown").select2({
        data: arr
})
```

As far as installation is concerned, all that I have done is copy the follwing files to my `js` folder and included this line `<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>` in my html.

```
select2.js
select2.min.js
select2.full.js
select2.full.min.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the error. I had included a `select2.min.js` file from a previous `Select2` version(below `v4.0`) and that was overriding the actions of the newer version. When I removed that and just kept the newer version things worked fine.